# How to know how long will my simulation run in UNIX?

Tags: bash

[image]

I am new in using Unix, I want to know what command can display how long will my simulation run. I am using windows but running cygwin to get the UNIX environment. I am running a discrete dipole approximation simulation.

This is my simulation, I don't know if it worked or not that is why I want to see the remaining time to ensure it is really running, or is there any way to know if it is really running?

Comment: If your simulation doesn't provide some indication of progress (x% done, time remaining) either written to stdout or a log file there is no way to know how long the simulation is going to take.

Comment: Where can I see this stdout?

Comment: If you don't redirect it in the terminal. The four lines starting with "PID   PPID...." are the stdout for the command `ps`.

Comment: if `ddscat` is your simulation, it has finished/exited as can be seen from the `[1]+ Exit 127` output. Try running `ddscat` without `>&  ddscat.out &` if you don't understand what that is doing.

Comment: @Anthon you mean the format is "$ ddscat" only?

Comment: `$` is your prompt, `ddscat` is your command.

Comment: And maybe you should try adding your current directory to your path or use `./ddscat` as command.

Comment: Yes I already added but still when I opened the ddscat.out file, it said that no such file or directory

Comment: If you do `ls -l ../../src/ddscat` do you actually see a file/program?

Comment: @Anthon Oh! It said no such file or directory, so that means there is no ddscat file right?

Comment: If you make a link to a program that doesn't exist, it is unlikely that you actually run it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

There is in general no way to predict how long a command *will* take *before* it runs, only how long it took after it has finished. It might be possible for your particular command, but we can't help you with this since we don't know anything about it.

Comment: @Christopher I edited my post and showed the image of my simulation, I want to know how to ensure that it is really running. Is there any way?

Comment: The line starting with `[1]+  Exit 127` indicates that your program has exited and that an error has occurred. Look in `ddscat.out` to see if you have any error message there.

Comment: Yes it said "-bash: ddscat: command not found" so what is wrong?

Comment: Oh, I overlooked that, you need to run the command as `./ddscat`, not just `ddscat`.

Comment: And in the future, please copy-and-paste your text instead of taking a screenshot, you can copy text from the Cygwin terminal with a right-click.

Comment: @fkraiem Which command are you pertaining in the screenshot?

Comment: Your third command (which is the only time you run `ddscat` as a command).

Comment: @fkraiem I already added changed the command but when I opened the ddscat.out it said that no such file or directory